# Magento 2: get Data by store id

Tags: magento2, uicomponent

I have a custom module developed and it stores data by the store id that is selected in the admin form. All the data is stored in a separate table while store data is stored in a separate table. now I want to display that stored data by store id.
Can someone explain me how to do this?

Answer (score 2):

To get collection by store filter

```
$collection = $this->collectionFactory->create()
          ->addFieldToFilter('store_id',$this->storeManager->getStore()->getId());
```

Comment: did this solution work ?